# App Notifications: Website with facebook notifications

Tags: facebook

The FB documentation reads:

```
Only apps on Facebook.com can use App Notifications.
```

Does that mean that only Canvas apps can use notifications. Or is it possible for Web apps that are non canvas integration to use App notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Canvas apps can use the `Notifications API` of facebook.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Does this mean that if I am using a Web app that has a number of permissions from the user and can post feed stories, pictures etc. on the user's timeline, I cannot still send notifications.

Comment: Exactly. But you can use other APIs like `Send Requests` depending on your need. 
P.S. you can mark this as correct if that helped